# Nested padding LESS

Tags: button, nested, less, html-lists, padding

I am trying to create indentation for buttons that sit inside of a nested ul li structure.

I can't change the HTML as it is being rendered by a third party system.

The HTML

```
    <ul>
       <li><button>Parent</button>
           <ul>
            <li>
              <button> Child</button>
                 <li><button>Parent</button>
                   <ul>
                    <li>
                     <button> Sibling etc</button>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
```

The ul and li have no margin or padding so the idea was to simply add padding to the button elements.

The issue is, because of the ul having no margin/padding, the buttons all start from the exact same point and there (no matter how deep they are nested) all have the exact same indentation.

LESS

```
    ul{
    li{
      button{
        padding-left: 25px;
      }
      ul{
        li{
          button{
            padding-left: 35px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I thought of doing something like the above (and account for as many levels as possible) but it would be a nightmare to maintain.

Surely there is a more elegant way to handle this, thoughts?

Comment: "The issue is, because of the ul having no margin/padding" - only if you use something like [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), if you don't (or using some alternative like [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)) in most standard browsers `<ul>` does have corresponding padding. Either way, if you want to fix it on your own you should set padding/margin for just `<ul>` and not to individual buttons (unless you need non-uniform intend for each nesting level). [For example](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/wKKMaq).

Comment: I can't add padding to the ul,  I need to add padding to each nested button to create the effect of a standard ul list. As per my question, I am looking for a cleaner way of doing this without having to manually create each level, ideally, a LESS loop or mixin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>I don't know why you would want to go as far as to write a mixin for this.</del>

<del>My solution in LESS:</del>

```
ul ul button {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
ul ul ul button {
   padding-left: 35px;
}
```

<del>Would that solve the problem for you?
The resulting CSS would look like this:</del>

```
ul ul button {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
ul ul ul button {
    padding-left: 35px;
}
```

Alright, so I thought of a different solution and looked at the LESS documentation but the underlying problem is that you can't know the number of levels of nesting coming into play beforehand obviously.

Thus you would have to wait for the HTML to be rendered, then read out the level of nesting (e.g. 5 levels) and based on that you could generate the CSS, which I'm afraid wouldn't make much sense and is something to be done in JavaScript.

All of that being said you could use a few variables to ease your writing process in LESS but that's about it. Here for an example:

```
@padding: 25px;
@addten: 10px;
@selector: ul button;

@selector { @padding; }
ul @selector { @padding + @addten; }
ul ul @selector { @padding + @addten*2; }
ul ul ul @selector { @padding + @addten*3; }
```

Probably you could also create a mixin for that to add another layer of abstraction but like I said, I wouldn't go thus far.

Hope this helps. =)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Marco. The nesting is controlled by data being loaded from an external system, your answer is nearly right but stops working after a certain level of nesting. I thought having a LESS loop or mixin would eliminate me having to manually create the indentation, I could extend your code and account for another 3 levels but I thought there could be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Ah. I see. Well, I'm not a big fan of abstraction (variables = ok, mixins = ok, too much logic in my LESS = not ok), hence this pretty straight forward solution. =)

Comment: I altered my suggested solution. May be that can help you out but I think what you want do is solving a problem of logic with the wrong tool. LESS won't help you with the problem at hand from my understanding.

Comment: Thank you Marco. While not ideal it will save me having to manually create each level if there are any changes to the amount of indentation required.